# Scala Hello World: NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear

Tags: scala

When I try to compile a simple hello world program in Scala:

`Hello.scala`:

```
object Hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("hello world")
    }
}
```

with `scalac Hello.scala`. I get

```
error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:61)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:40)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:49)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:395)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:401)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1607)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:61)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:40)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:49)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:395)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:401)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1607)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

on Ubuntu 18 with `scalac` version `2.11.12` and java version `1.8.0_181`. Strangely, this same program will compile and run on macOS with `scalac` version `2.12.6` and java `1.8.0_111`.

My two questions are: why does this happen? How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference as it's platform independent, as long as you have all the required dependencies.

Comment: @zenwraight Indeed. That's why I'm confused about this behavior.

Comment: Looks like the same issue reported in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876388/scala-script-wont-run-on-ubuntu).

Comment: How many java version do you have on windows ?

Comment: @LeoC That link suggests that upgrading to scala 2.12 solves the problem. Am I correct in therefore concluding that hello world only works on scala 2.12?

Comment: @zenwraight I'm not on Windows.

Comment: No my doubt is you might be having java 8 and java 9 and that jar is being compiled using java 9 or something like that, that's why i asked do u have multiple java versions installed ?

Comment: @zenwraight I am under the impression that I have only Java 8 installed.

Comment: does your scala REPL load OK? I recommend re-installing scala and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @terminally-chill repl loads fine.

Comment: @JonDeaton what is output when you check `javac -version` in command line?

Comment: @terminally-chill 1.8.0_181

Comment: Upgrade to Scala version 2.12.6. It should compile successfully.

Answer (score 2):

With scala 2.11.12, I had to install openjdk version "10.0.2". This was done with the command `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` weirdly enough.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

I was getting the same error when running openjdk version 8.

Comment: I don't think the compatibility matrix alone explains it. I've expanded my answer in another similar question to explain the reason for the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51223234/5180989